# How to add "open link in app mode" to right-click menu in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

app mode: chrome window without navigation panel(address+tab bars). Run this in terminal

```
google-chrome --app=http://stackoverflow.com/
```

I want to open a website in app mode directly from chrome. Is there an extension that adds such option? If not how do I write a small extension that does just that? I never wrote a chrome extension but I have some experience with html and javascript. Thanks

Edit: Main issue is chrome.windows.create has no "app" option for [CreateType](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-CreateType). I guess we can't do anything about it.

Comment: What's your use case? Do you need a particular website, or be able to do it with an arbitrary one? Define "directly from Chrome".

Comment: "directly from chrome" - without running `google-chrome --app=` in terminal. I want an option to open sites without tab/navigation bar.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way using [`chrome.management` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management).

```
chrome.management.generateAppForLink("http://stackoverflow.com/", "Stack Overflow", function(info) {
  chrome.management.setLaunchType(info.id, "OPEN_AS_WINDOW", function() {
    chrome.management.launchApp(info.id);
  })
});
```

Note that the above code requires a user gesture (which is undocumented). For examples, see [Invoking `activeTab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab#invoking-activeTab). Activating a context menu should be sufficient as a gesture.

However, this will create an app in the app launcher permanently. On the plus side, it will not create duplicates for the same URL/Title.

You can call `chrome.management.uninstall(id)`, but it will require a confirmation from the user.